# Using 'content_for' inside a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used `content_for` inside a view. This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <%= content_for :youtube_explain %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<% content_for :youtube_explain do %>
  <div>
    物件　⇒　<%= link_to "ント（編）", "https://youtu.be/ZYhR" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It does not seem to display the content in block `youtube_explain`.

Comment: Your code seems correct as per [DOCS](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for). But, can you try `<%= yield :youtube_explain %>` instead of `<%= content_for :youtube_explain %>`

Comment: i tried to use `yield` as your comment, but it didn't show.

Comment: @sawa my question is block html code which i put inside `content_for` didn't display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your block of markup before you call it, like:

```
<%= content_for? :youtube_explain %>

<% content_for :youtube_explain do %>
  <div>物件　⇒　<%= link_to "ント（編）", "https://youtu.be/ZYhR" %></div>
<% end %>

<!-- false -->
```

Otherwise:

```
<% content_for :youtube_explain do %>
  <div>物件　⇒　<%= link_to "ント（編）", "https://youtu.be/ZYhR" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= content_for? :youtube_explain %>

<!-- true -->
```